# How can I emit a SwarmEvent::Behaviour from a derived NetworkBehaviour?

Tags: rust, p2p, libp2p

I'm looking to write a network behavior that utilizes mDNS, floodsub, and a kademlia DHT. So far, I've gotten each of these services to work, but haven't been able to use the responses from these services for anything meaningful.

Ideally, I'd be able to pipe the data that comes from a behavior process event, like one that would be implemented for a Kad DHT, into the main Swarm `poll` loop. For example, in my case, I have a reference to a struct representing a graph that is persisted to the disk through the `sled` database. Ownership of this struct exists in the method that is polling the swarm. How would I go about updating this graph (e.g. adding an entry) when a `KademliaEvent` is received?

Solutions I've tried:

- Moving ownership of the data structure I want to update to the `ClientBehavior` struct so I can just `self.my_data_structure.add(result);` from the `KademliaEvent` `inject_event` method

  - `#[derive(NetworkBehaviour)]` does NOT like this at all
  - `Graph` is just a struct, and doesn't emit any events / implement `NetworkBehaviour`
- Creating a `Context` struct that `derive`s `NetworkBehaviour` and can be used to pipe a response back and forth between the polling method and the respective `inject_event` method

  - `#[derive(NetworkBehaviour)]` doesn't place nice with `Arc`s / `Mutex`es

Here's what my NetworkBehavior looks like:

```rust
/// A network behavior describing a client connected to a pub-sub compatible,
/// optionally mDNS-compatible network. Such a "behavior" may be implemented for
/// any libp2p transport, but any transport used with this behavior must implement
/// asynchronous reading & writing capabilities.
#[derive(NetworkBehaviour)]
pub struct ClientBehavior<TSubstream: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Send + Unpin + 'static> {
    /// Some pubsub mechanism bound to the above transport
    pub floodsub: Floodsub<TSubstream>,

    /// Some mDNS service bound to the above transport
    pub mdns: Mdns<TSubstream>,

    /// Allow for the client to do some external discovery on the global network through a KAD DHT
    pub kad_dht: Kademlia<TSubstream, MemoryStore>,
}
```

and what my Kademlia `NetworkBehaviourEventProceess` implementation looks like:

```rust
impl<TSubstream: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Send + Unpin + 'static>
    NetworkBehaviourEventProcess<KademliaEvent> for ClientBehavior<TSubstream>
{
    fn inject_event(&mut self, event: KademliaEvent) {
        // Some behavior logic, nothing special, really, just a bunch of matches
        // NOTE: this is when I'd want to update the `Graph`, since KademliaEvent will contain data that I need to put in the `Graph` instance
    }
}
```

and how I'm spawning my `Swarm`, and my `ClientBehavior`:

```rust
// Initialize a new behavior for a client that we will generate in the not-so-distant future with the given peerId, alongside
// an mDNS service handler as well as a floodsub instance targeted at the given peer
let mut behavior = ClientBehavior {
    floodsub: Floodsub::new(self.peer_id.clone()),
    mdns: Mdns::new().await?,
    kad_dht: Kademlia::new(self.peer_id.clone(), store),
};

// Iterate through bootstrap addresses
for bootstrap_peer in bootstrap_addresses {
    // NOTE: add_address is a method that isn't provided by #[derive(NetworkBehaviour)].
    // It's just a helper method I wrote that adds the peer to the Floodsub & DHT views.
    behavior.add_address(&bootstrap_peer.0, bootstrap_peer.1); // Add the bootstrap peer to the DHT
}

// Bootstrap the behavior's DHT
behavior.kad_dht.bootstrap();

// Note: here, `self` is a reference to a configuration struct holding a peer ID, and a keypair
let mut swarm = Swarm::new(
    libp2p::build_tcp_ws_secio_mplex_yamux(self.keypair.clone())?,
    behavior,
    self.peer_id.clone(),
); // Initialize a swarm
```

and how I'm polling the swarm:

```rust
// NOTE: Here, `self` has ownership of the aforementioned `Graph` instance. I'd like to update this
// instance from this block, or from the ClientBehavior itself--as long as I'm able to update it once a `KademliaEvent` is received.

// Try to get the address we'll listen on
if let Ok(addr) = format!("/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/{}", port).parse::<Multiaddr>() {
    // Try to tell the swarm to listen on this address, return an error if this doesn't work
    if let Err(e) = Swarm::listen_on(&mut swarm, addr.clone()) {
        // Convert the addr err into an io error
        let e: std::io::Error = io::ErrorKind::AddrNotAvailable.into();

        // Return an error
        return Err(e.into());
    };

    // Fetch the hash of the first transaction in the DAG from the network
    swarm
        .kad_dht
        .get_record(&Key::new(&sync::ROOT_TRANSACTION_KEY), Quorum::Majority);

    loop {
        // Poll the swarm
        match swarm.next_event().await {
            // NOTE: Initially, I was under the impression that I would be able to intercept
            // events from the ClientBehavior here. Yet, the below info! call is never reached.
            // This remains the case in libp2p example code that I have experimented with.
            SwarmEvent::Behaviour(e) => info!("idk: {:?}", e),

            _ => debug!("Some other event; this is handled specifically in the actual codebase, but for this question, all I really care about is the above behavior event."),
        };
    }
}
```

Will I just have to implement `NetworkBehaviour` myself?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to your question, but maybe this will help:

> Moving ownership of the data structure I want to update to the ClientBehavior struct so I can just self.my_data_structure.add(result); from the KademliaEvent inject_event method
>
> - #[derive(NetworkBehaviour)] does NOT like this at all
> - Graph is just a struct, and doesn't emit any events / implement NetworkBehaviour

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/libp2p/0.22.0/libp2p/swarm/trait.NetworkBehaviour.html) has the following to say on that:

> #[behaviour(ignore)] can be added on a struct field to disable generation of delegation to the fields which do not implement NetworkBehaviour.

Since it otherwise requires all the fields to implement the *NetworkBehaviour* trait.
That should make that a viable solution.

Either way though, if you are trying to modify a structure which exceeds the scope of your *Mdns*I believe¹ that the most idiomatic solution to all of this would be emitting a custom event via the *poll* function (return a `Poll::Ready(GenerateEvent(TOut))`) which you can then listen on via a different *NetworkBehaviourEventProcess* impl for the corresponding struct which should then modify the struct.
Similar to how the [libp2p-ping implementation](https://docs.rs/crate/libp2p-ping/0.20.0/source/src/lib.rs) uses a VecDeque event queue which is then propagated during `poll()` you could have a similar queue (marked `behaviour(ignore)]`) in your *ClientBehaviour*, append to it, emit the event in `poll()` and catch that specific event in your calling code/await loop somehow?

*Edit*: you [should also be able to extend the poll method](https://docs.rs/libp2p-core-derive/0.20.1/src/libp2p_core_derive/lib.rs.html#383-385) to allow for returning additional events that way.

¹: I'm nowhere near competent enough with rust-libp2p and by far not experienced enough to give hard facts, your question was sort of a tutorial for me actually